# WPF how to access parent usercontrol's property in child usercontrol?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hi I am using with WPF PRISM architecture.

I have two usercontrols: Parent View--ParentViewModel ChildView -- ChildViewModel Both have their own viewmodels. Now that I have injected UCChild into UCParent. But I want to access a property ("UCParent.DataContext.ChildForeground") in the Parent usercontrol UCParent. How do I able to get the parent's DataContext.Property?

I have tried dependency properties but, didn't help. Below is the parent's xaml.cs. Initialize component of parent control's xaml.cs clears the dependency property, before creating the child control.

```
public partial class ParentView : UserControl
{
ParentViewModel vm = new ParentViewModel();

public ParentView()
{
this.DataContext = vm;
InitializeComponent;
}
}
```

I am trying to **pass parent control's property as a parameter to child control's viewmodel constructor.** I am creating the instance of the child usercontrol in xaml.

Comment: You can do that easily in XAML using a [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx) `Binding`.

Comment: @Sheridan How can it be done through code?